# .htaccess to redirect any URL from a domain to a fixed URL on another domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, redirect

Anyone can help me out with an .htaccess I'm trying to create?

I want to redirect ***foo.com*** to ***foo.ca***.

Any URL from ***foo.com*** (with or without www and under http or https) will all be redirected to ***www.foo.ca***.

Some examples:

- http://www.foo.com/ --> http://www.foo.ca/ (http + www)
- https://www.foo.com/ --> http://www.foo.ca/ (https + www)
- http://foo.com/bar/ --> http://www.foo.ca/ (http + some url)
- https://foo.com/bar/ --> http://www.foo.ca/ (https + some url)
- http://www.foo.com/bar/ --> http://www.foo.ca/ (http + www + some url)
- https://www.foo.com/bar --> http://www.foo.ca/ (https + www + some url)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.foo.ca$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.foo.ca/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Remove the $1 and it'll work like the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I'm not an expert, I have created functional redirects using .htaccess. Anyway, I think you'll need a redirect (from .com to .ca) in the root folder of the .com version like so

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.foo.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In my opinion, the previously posted suggestion by Jeff Clark would rewrite non-www urls to www-included urls of the .ca version and only works in the root folder where the .ca version is located.

In addition, specifying 301 ensures that the search engines transfer any merit to the new domain as well.